Displaying student course timetables graphically using python and pandas
I have a pandas dataframe of course timetables and I want to be able to display the information graphically- something like this:

I had no idea how to go about this so I asked ChatGPT 3.5, which suggested using a matplotlib bar chart. After a fair amount of back and forth and modifying code I got this code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'CCode': ['BABM701','BABM701', 'DCFE700', 'MG6051', 'DCFE700', 'MG6051'],
    'SG': ['All','All',  'All', 'A', 'All','A'],
    'StartTime': ['09:00:00','13:00:00', '09:00:00','09:00:00', '13:00:00','10:00:00'],
    'EndTime': ['12:00:00', '14:30:00','14:30:00','12:00:00', '14:30:00','12:00:00'],
    'Day': ['Mon', 'Mon','Mon', 'Thu', 'Thu','Fri'],
    'Room': ['X310','X310', 'K312','K225', 'K312','K225']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the 'StartTime' and 'EndTime' to datetime format
df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
df['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time

# Get unique CCode values and assign colors automatically
unique_ccodes = df['CCode'].unique()
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_ccodes)))  # Using tab20 colormap
color_map = {ccode: colors[i] for i, ccode in enumerate(unique_ccodes)}

# Create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# Set the y-position for the bars
y_positions = {'Mon': 4, 'Tue': 3, 'Wed': 2, 'Thu': 1, 'Fri': 0}

# Find the earliest start time and latest end time
earliest_start = min(9, df['StartTime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour + x.minute/60).min())
latest_end = max(17, df['EndTime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour + x.minute/60).max())

# Adjust y-positions based on overlaps
for day in df['Day'].unique():
    day_df = df[df['Day'] == day].sort_values(by='StartTime')
    overlap_count = np.zeros(len(day_df))
    
    for i in range(len(day_df)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(day_df)):
            if day_df.iloc[i]['EndTime'] > day_df.iloc[j]['StartTime'] and day_df.iloc[i]['StartTime'] < day_df.iloc[j]['EndTime']:
                overlap_count[j] += 1
                
    day_df['Overlap'] = overlap_count
    
    # Plot bars for the day with adjusted height for overlapping courses
    for idx, row in day_df.iterrows():
        duration = (pd.Timestamp.combine(pd.Timestamp.today(), row['EndTime']) - pd.Timestamp.combine(pd.Timestamp.today(), row['StartTime'])).seconds/3600
        x_position = row['StartTime'].hour + row['StartTime'].minute/60
        y_position = y_positions[day] - row['Overlap'] * 0.5  # Adjusting y position based on overlap
        plt.barh(y=y_position, width=duration, left=x_position, color=color_map[row['CCode']], alpha=0.7, edgecolor='grey', label=row['CCode'])
        
        # Annotate the bar with CCode and SG
        label = f"{row['CCode']} {row['SG']}"
        plt.text(x=x_position + duration/2, y=y_position, s=label, color='black', va='center', ha='center')

# Customize the plot
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Day')
plt.title('Course Schedule')
plt.xlim(earliest_start, latest_end)
plt.xticks(np.arange(earliest_start, latest_end + 1, 1))
plt.yticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], ['Fri', 'Thu', 'Wed', 'Tue', 'Mon'])
plt.grid(axis='x', linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.tight_layout()

# Show the plot
plt.show()

Which genereates this output:

This is pretty close to what I want- except it isn't handling overlapping courses properly. Ideally I would like to display courses with time overlaps stacked on top of each other, as in the example timetable. This code has tried to do that (though not well) for the first overlap on Monday morning, then completely missed the overlap on Monday afternoon. I tried getting ChatGPT to fix this but this is the best it came up with, all it's subsequent fixes made it worse.
I can kind of see how I might go about fixing this but it feels like it would be very clunky:

Starting from Friday (because its at the bottom of the chart), work out how many overlapping courses there are, use that to set the y-position of Friday and then lay out the bars, then work back through the days.
An alternative and possibly easier way would be to ignore overlaps and simply count how many courses are in each day and offset them all, regardless of whether they are overlapping or not. This would mean that courses that don't overlap aren't nicely in line, as in the example, but that is acceptable if alternatives are too hard.

I'm sure there should be an easier way to achieve a similar result, so I'm looking for ideas please.
I thought of using a grouped bar chart, grouped by day. I think this would produce a similar result to my idea 2) above, but it should do it automatically? I asked ChatGPT but the code it wrote for this produced terrible results. I also briefly tried it in plotly. If you think grouped bar chart is the right way to go please let me know.
I also thought if the bar chart could display overlapping courses in a different way (e.g. alternating diagonal bands of colour instead of the blend of colour it is using now?) to make the overlap clearer. Again I asked ChatGPT but the results were terrible.
Please let me know if you have any good ideas on how to achieve something like the result I want. I just don't want to spend ages fixing what I have if there is a better chart type/better library/neat coding trick that I should be using.
A couple of final notes: Overlapping courses are not common, which is why I would prefer to keep non-overlapping courses in line horizontally if possible. It is possible more than 2 courses could be overlapping so the solution needs to be able to handle this.

Here's a suggestion using plotly: since plotly can't handle only time, I give it a temporary date, and then use the x-axis scale to show only time. The issue with this timeline graph is the spacing between days of the week. The width of the graph can be adjusted, but overlapping occurs. To resolve this, we need to adjust the placement of the graph with the y-axis as the numeric axis. Then change to a string of days of the week.
import datetime
dt = datetime.date.today()
df['StartTime'] = df['StartTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.combine(dt, x))
df['EndTime'] = df['EndTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.combine(dt, x))

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.timeline(df,
                  x_start='StartTime',
                  x_end='EndTime',
                  y='Day',
                  color='CCode',
                  text=[row[1]+' '+row[2] for row in df[['CCode','SG']].itertuples()])
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat='%H:%M')

fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()



Thanks @r-beginners, that output looks promising. However when I run this code I get this error
TypeError: Object of type timedelta is not JSON serializable
Can you tell me how to fix this please?

Can you tell us a little more about the error situation? Have you just added a date to your time data? Or is it the Plotly code part?

I took the original code I posted in the question, deleted everything below the "# Get unique CCode values and assign colors automatically" comment and pasted the code from your answer instead.

That runs nicely in Colab, but gives the JSON error in Spyder (my usual IDE)- it also gives the same error in IDLE and Jupyter Notebook. All of these are from Anaconda3, Spyder is using Python 3.11.5

Which version of pandas do you use? In my environment, pandas:1.4.4, plotly:5.20.0 and Colab is pandas:2.0.3, plotly:5.15.0.

In Spyder, Pandas 2.1.4 and Plotly 5.9.0. I updated Plotly (to 5.19.0) and now it runs- thanks for your help :)
